# jQuery different events on different elements to trigger the same function

Tags: javascript, jquery

What if different elements have to trigger the same function but on different events ?

```
$('#btnNext').on('click', function() { /*Same thing*/ });

$('#txtField').on('change blur', function() { /*Same thing*/ });
```

Is there any way to integrate these two lines, so I can write the same lines of code just once ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You included a clue in your question: *"trigger the* same *function"* - so simply bind the *same* function:

```
function commonHandler(e) { /* your code */ }

$('#btnNext').on('click', commonHandler);

$('#txtField').on('change blur', commonHandler);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#btnNext').on('click', myMethod );

$('#txtField').on('change blur',  myMethod );

function myMethod()
{
/*Your Code goes here*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a jsFiddle For You

> [Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/T2SkB/2/)

```
 function Commonalert(){alert("Common Alert Message");}

$('#Btn').on('click', Commonalert);

$('#text').on('change blur', Commonalert);
```